# Android custom call receiving application

Tags: android, call, message, priority-queue

I want to develop an Android application for priority based call receiving. This application will contain a list of contacts which have different priorities. It will manage calls according to priority, .e.g if a low priority call is being used, mean while a higher priority person calls me, then the application will switch to higher priority call leaving a text message to low priority call.

I have no Idea how to build this.

1. Receive call on the application
2. Manage call
3. Send auto message

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) with priority broadcast. Seems like solution to me. It is a bit tricky if you haven't worked with this before, but have a look at google's implementation of actual phone application [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone.git). Choose appropriate app to your planned API.

Comment: No matter just look in code how they did it and do something similar, ofc i didn't say to copy/paste source.